# save a image from CameraCaptureUI to a folder

Tags: c#, directory, camera

i need to save the picture getting from the camera in a specific folder but i can't find the way, i онли  show it in the xaml.

```
        class CameraOpening{
        public async Task<SoftwareBitmapSource> PhotoTake(){
            var captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
            captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
            captureUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = false;
            var photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
            var bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
            if (photo != null){
                var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(
                    "ProfilePhotoFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                await photo.CopyAsync(folder,"ProfilePhoto.jpg",NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                using (var stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)){
                    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                    var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
                    var softwareBitmapBGR8 = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(
                    softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

                    await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGR8);}
                await photo.DeleteAsync();}
            return bitmapSource;}}

    public async void Buttonfoto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cam = new CameraOpening();
        imageControl.Source = await cam.PhotoTake();
    }
```

and the xaml has the Image and the Button

there is a way for save the picture taken in a specific directory?
or a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Lines:

```
var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("ProfilePhotoFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
await photo.CopyAsync(folder, "ProfilePhoto.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

already seems to be saving your photo to path `./ProfilePhotoFolder/ProfilePhoto.jpg`.
But it will save only if picture was actually taken.

```
var photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
// < ... >
if (photo != null) { /* save file! */ }
```

Check what `captureUI.CaptureFileAsync` actually returns. 
If it's `null` - nothing will happen.

But if your photo is being taken and already saving itself to `./ProfilePhotoFolder/ProfilePhoto.jpg` you can save it again via:

```
await photo.CopyAsync(folder, "C:\\SomeFolder\\MyPhoto.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Or copy already created picture via:

```
File.Copy(".\\ProfilePhotoFolder\\ProfilePhoto.jpg", "C:\\SomeFolder\\MyPhoto.jpg");
```

More info here:
[System.IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io) and [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file)

Comment: i try to use 
File.Copy(".\\ProfilePhotoFolder\\ProfilePhoto.jpg", "C:\\SomeFolder\\MyPhoto.jpg");

Comment: but dont works the directory and the image is not found, the path is not there, the path of the C:\...\App1\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\ProfilePhotoFolder\ProfilePhoto.jpg'

(i simplify the path).

just use :
`File.Copy(".\\ProfilePhotoFolder\\ProfilePhoto.jpg", "C:\\Users\\Luis\\Documents\\MyPhoto.jpg")`